# Transpose and aggregate SQL query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, transpose

Hi i'm looking for help with a query. I currently have a table that looks like this:

```
 BP          I/E

AN02           I  
BN02           ECN  
EN89           ECN  
AN02           I  
BN02           ECC  
EN89           ECN  
AN02           ECC  
BN02           ECC  
EN89           ECN 
AN02           ECC  
BN02           ECN  
EN89           ECN 
AN02           I  
BN02           I 
EN89           ECN
```

Im looking to make an SQL query that counts the number of I's, ECN's, and ECC's per BP. Hopefully a query that would look like this:

```
BP    I    ECN   ECC  

AN02  2    3      1
BN02  1    6      9
EN89  4    2      3
```

Can anyone help? Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A crosstab may suit:

```
TRANSFORM Count(tbl.[I/E]) AS [CountOfI/E]
SELECT tbl.BP
FROM tbl
GROUP BY tbl.BP
PIVOT tbl.[I/E];
```

Result:

```
BP      ECC ECN I
AN02    2       3
BN02    2   2   1
EN89        5
```